# Drupal CKeditor - Text Formats dropdown is not visible for some user roles

Tags: drupal, ckeditor, wysiwyg

I have a Magazine Article content type, with a Body field. The body field is configured to use CKEditor. I also have a Magazine Editor role set up.

When logged in as Admin, I can see a "Text format" select box immediately below the editor textarea, with the usual options (Full HTML, Filtered HTML, Plain text, PHP code). When I am logged in as a Magazine Editor, the "Text format" box is not rendered to the page.

I would like, ideally, for the available text formats (depending on user role) to be displayed to all users in the select box. At a pinch, I'll take defaulting that body field to Full HTML for all users.

Under */admin/structure/types/manage/magazine-article/fields/body*:

- "Text processing" is set to "Filtered text (user selects text format)"
- "Limit allowed text formats" is unchecked
- "Override default order" is unchecked

Under */admin/config/content/ckeditor*:

- A "Magazine" profile has been defined. Its configured Input Formats are "Filtered HTML" and "Full HTML"

Under */admin/config/content/formats*:

- The "Full HTML" and "Filtered HTML" formats both have the "magazine editor" role assigned to them.

Under */admin/people/permissions*:

- The Magazine Editor role has permission to use both the "Full HTML" and "Filtered HTML" formats

**I've cleared caches. I've turned it off and on again. What have I missed?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just had this exact issue. In my case it was the Better Formats module I had installed. I had to enable appropriate permissions for non-administrator roles via /admin/people/permissions in the Better Formats section. Somehow the latest round of updates I did altered the permissions. If it's not that, I'm stumped too since it looks like you have everything set up right.

Comment: This does seem to have fixed it, many thanks. I had to add "Show format selection for nodes" permission to the Magazine Editor role, under the Better Formats module permissions.

Comment: Works for me. Thank you